# Rails 4.1: кастомный скаффолд

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Я новичок в Rails и мне приглянулись скаффолдинги.
Минус - шаблоны скаффолдингов стандартные, а хотелось бы использовать свою тему.
Вариант с гемом бутстрап не подходит. Хочу именно кастомизировать шаблоны. Я нашел в гугл, что надо поменять файлы внутри /lib/rails/scaffolding...
Проблема в том, что у меня нет в папке lib ничего подобного. Имеется папка assets и еще какая-то.
Где эти файлы искать? Или есть способ куда более изящнее кастомизировать шаблоны скаффолдинга?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо создать папку lib/templates/erb/scaffold/ в своем приложении и положить туда _form.erb.html

Файл _form.erb.html берем из рельсов, путь к гему, который содержит скаффолдинг: `bundle show railties`
Открываем гем, файл лежит тут: `lib/templates/erb/scaffold/_form.erb.html`
Копируем к себе, правим по вкусу.

Comment: спасибо попробую

Comment: Сделал все так как описано выше, но все равно не происходит ничего. Такое ощущение, что мои шаблоны как будто не подхватываются. Можнт надо что-то перезагружать?

Comment: Решение годится, более подробно описали тут http://daniel.fone.net.nz/blog/2014/02/01/customising-scaffold-views-in-ruby-on-rails/